# Verify data with public RSA 1024 Openssl key with openssl_verify()?

Tags: php, openssl

I got private_key.pem and public_key.pem. The public one is signed by bank.
To trying to verify data sent to me by bank i use php method openssl_verify()

So far i have no luck on verifying that data against their public key.
I always get those 2 errors:

> error:0407006A:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block
>   type is not 01
>
> error:04067072:rsa
>   routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding
>   check failed

I also did try to just verify it with shell_exec() method, but i get back same errors.

Anyone has seen this and maybe know how to verify it properly?

Comment: It looks like bank uses non-PKCS#1 compliant padding. Try to use openssl_decrypt() to see what's encrypted inside signature, maybe they just signed a hash, without a PKCS#1 padding

Comment: @ Nickolay O i'm not quite sure what kind of method i should use for openssl_decrypt(). I have 97 methods availiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be using OAEP padding.  It's PKCS#1 compliant (OAEP defined in PKCS#1 v2.0+) but it does differ from the sole padding scheme PKCS#1 v1.5 defined.

Anyway, my suggestion would be try decrypting it with [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  The maintainer of that package - unlike the maintainer of the OpenSSL PHP extension - actively support his product.

Comment: Thanks for great phpseclib link. Used that classes to try and verify and getting back unverified. Totally stuck here dunno wheres problem why it fails. Also how could i debug this?

Comment: @arma: Wow. Did you grab some cash while you were at it?!

Comment: @SedateAlien Haha, that was long time ago :) And i didn't know what im was talking about :D